# Is a primary key field NOT NULL by default in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, constraints, primary-key

Is a primary key field NOT NULL by default in postgres, or does it need to be specified as such when creating the table?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS)

> Adding a primary key will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns listed in the primary key, and will force the column(s) **to be marked `NOT NULL`**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>